# Bitboard 64-bit machine: should I use int16 or int64 for a 4x4 board?

Tags: performance, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 16-bit, bitboard

I'm programming a 4x4 board game in C++ using bitboards in a 64-bit machine. I only need 16 bits to implement the board. Should I use:

- **uint16_t** - to reduce used space?
- **uint64_t** - if operations are(?) faster with 64-bit integers, should I use them and mask the value with 0xFFFF (bitwise AND) when necessary?
- **uint_fast16_t** - I just discovered this integer type, but I'm not sure how it works and if I would need a mask too?

I don't know if it helps, but my processor is: *Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz*

Comment: Just use `int` and let the compiler do what it is good at.

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do with that board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are looking to save space, use `uint16_t`.
- If you are looking to save time, use `uint_fast16_t`.
- `uint64_t` may be useful, too, for making an array of values aligned at 8-byte boundaries. This is unlikely to give you much benefits, though, because it comes at the price of wasting 75% of memory allocated for the array, along with the associated loss in cache performance.

Note: you may end up using the same type as `uint64_t` if your library maps `uint_fast16_t` to `uint64_t`.

Comment: To be safe with **uint_fast16_t**, I should mask the number when I do left shifts right?

Edit: in case I do right shifts later.

Comment: @Hydrametr0nice This is correct. The system will not automatically zero out the most-significant bits outside of the 16 bits that you want to keep, so if you shift the value right at some later time, these bits would be shifted back into your value. You may want to postpone masking off the high bits until the time that you do the right shifting.